# Reverse for '' with no arguments not found when passing and retrieving parameters between views

Tags: python, django, redirect

Django version: 1.10
Basically, I want users who have logged in to go to the page with their own data.
So, when the user provides login credentials, redirect to some other page bypassing 'pk' so the page will have only data related to that 'pk'.

I have seen other posts in StackOverflow about Reverse for '' with no arguments not found but I don't know why this is not working for me so many insights and solutions are highly appreciated

In urls.py of the main project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls,name='admin'),
    url(r'^basic_app/',include('basic_app.urls',namespace='basic_app')),]
```

And I have an app named basic-app which contains urls.py as

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from basic_app import views

app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
         url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
         url(r'^class/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.ClassroomView,name='classroom_list'), ]
```

In views.py, I have a user login view that should send parameters as

```py
def user_login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                # then send the user to Classroom view with 'pk' as parameter
                return redirect(reverse('basic_app:classroom_list'), {'pk': user.id})
```

I should get 'pk' from LoginView in the following ClassroomView:

```py
def ClassroomView(request,pk):
    
        classroom_list = Classroom.objects\
                            .filter(school__user=User.objects.get(pk=request.session.get('user_id','0')))
        class_dict = {'class_records': classroom_list}
        return render(request, 'basic_app/classroom_list.html', context=class_dict)
```

But, it says

```
Reverse for 'classroom_list' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['basic_app/class/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

And, the url shows the following without 'pk'

http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/login/

The problem, I think lies in **return redirect()**. If I just write the following:
`return redirect('basic_app:classroom_list', {'pk': user.id})`

It gives the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /basic_app/login/
Reverse for 'classroom_list' with arguments '({'pk': 2},)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['basic_app/class/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

So, how can I link to the URL below by passing the argument?

```py
url(r'^class/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.ClassroomView,name='classroom_list')
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with main project urls.py and the django version ?

Comment: More important is the code that actually tries to do the reverse mapping.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply!! i have updated the contents so please tell what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Have you tried `return redirect(reverse('classroom_list', kwargs={'pk': user.id}))` ?

Comment: thanx @Asher i did try using kwargs, but silly me i used return redirect(reverse('classroom_list'), kwargs={'pk': user.id}) before so it was throwing error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

syntax is:

```
reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)
```

so

```
return redirect(reverse('basic_app:classroom_list', kwargs={'pk': user.id}))
```

Comment: Do we need `reverse('basic_app:classroom_list'`? because we are trying to access the url from the same app. So `reverse('classroom_list'` enough?

Comment: I think when there is a namespace it has to be mentioned.